# Getting part of the raw SQL in Rails API response for not found records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, rails-models

I created a Rails 5 app with `config.api_only` set to true, and implemented a controller action that deletes a record in a scoped model `Message` the problem is that when I try to delete a record that doesn't exist, the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception message includes part of the SQL query that is used in the scope, is possible to not include that SQL in the exception message?

Code of the model:

```rails
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope(:active) { where(active: true) }
end
```

Code of the controller

```rails
class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def delete
    message = Message.active.find(params[:id])
    begin
      message.destroy
      head :accepted # 202
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => error
      render json: { error: error.message }, status: 404
    end
  end
end
```

I would expect to get the next response if I send a wrong ID:

```json
{
    "error": "Couldn't find Message with 'id'=23444"
}
```

But instead, I'm getting this error:

```json
{
    "error": "Couldn't find Message with 'id'=23444 [WHERE \"message\".\"active\" = $1]"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no configuration to change the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` Exception error message. The best thing you can do is fetch for the Message without the scope and then check if it's active or not before performing the destroy and return appropriate error message.

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def delete
    message = Message.find(params[:id])
    if message.active
      message.destroy
      head :accepted # 202
    else
      render json: { error: "Couldn't find Message with 'id'=#{params[:id]}" }, status: 404
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => error
    render json: { error: error.message }, status: 404
  end
end
```

Comment: This workaround works perfectly for mi situation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running your application in 'development' mode when you are seeing the SQL part in the error message. By default, Rails will no longer include that information when running in 'production' mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is happening in production as well